# iOS OVH API Send SMS Error

Tags: php, ios, sms-gateway

I'm trying to execute a PHP script inside my iOS app. It have later to send SMS automatically with the OVH SMS gateway, but for the moment, I only try to connect with my IDs to this service without sending anything.

I get an error 500 (server internal error), and I can't see where is the problem. Here is the tutorial I'm following (in french) : https://www.ovh.com/fr/g1639.envoyer_des_sms_avec_lapi_ovh_en_php

And this is my script (I verified secret keys and it seems to be good, but I don't understand what is the "POST" line commented at the top) :

```
<?php
/**
 * # Instantiate. Visit https://eu.api.ovh.com/createToken/
 * to get your credentials
 * GET /sms/
 * GET /sms/sms-XXXXXX-1/jobs/
 * POST /sms/sms-XXXXXX-1/jobs/
 */

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use \Ovh\Api;

$applicationKey = "XXX";
$applicationSecret = "XXX"; 
$consumer_key = "XXX";

$endpoint = 'ovh-eu';

$conn = new Api($applicationKey,
                $applicationSecret,
                $endpoint,
                $consumer_key);

$smsServices = $conn->get('/sms/');

foreach ($smsServices as $smsService) {

    print_r($smsService);

    echo '{"success":1,"error_message":"All clear"}';
}
```

?>

And finally my Swift request :

```
func sendSmsAutoRequest(completionHandler: (responseObject: NSDictionary?, error: NSError?) -> ()) {
    let prefs = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    let username = prefs.stringForKey("username")!
    let messageText = prefs.stringForKey("messagetext")!
    let parameters = ["contactsSms": contactsSms, "username": username, "messageText": messageText]
    request(.POST, "http://XX.XX.XXX.XXX/dontworry/sendSms.php", parameters: parameters as? [String : AnyObject]).responseJSON { request, response, json, error in
        completionHandler(responseObject: json as? NSDictionary, error: error) }
}
```